# How to add class "form-control" to generated bootstrap-tags-input?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

Im using bootstrap tags input inside a modal that i display after ajax call.

Now i want to add class "form-control" to the generated input tag.

I tried like this :

$(".bootstrap-tagsinput > input").addClass('form-control');

but it dosent work for me.

Here is the input generated :

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
   <input type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `>` symbol

```js
$(".bootstrap-tagsinput input").addClass('form-control');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Reference:

- [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

  - [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)
  - [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: i tried like this                         $("#share_collection_container").html(result.share_collection_modal)
$(".bootstrap-tagsinput input").addClass('form-control');
$("#share_collection").modal("show");
but still not working

Comment: I need all html, i answer your question this is others detail